# How to dynamically return number or string with one function?

Tags: c, function, return-type

How can I return a string or a number within one function.

Such as:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%s",rawinput("What is your name: ", "s"));
    printf("%d", rawinput("How old are you: ", "n"));
}

([int] or [char *]) rawinput(char *message, char *type)
{

if(!strcmp(type,"n")){
  int value;
  scanf("%d",&value);
  return value;}
else if(!strcmp(type, "s")){
  char *value[1024];
  fgets(value,1024,stdin);
  return value;}
}
```

Note that the way of defining the rawinput function changes based.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: How to return a number or a string with the same function. Would it have to be done with an array?

Comment: You have to return a union or struct. This is wrong char *value[1024]; use `char value[1024];`. You don't need 1024 string pointers.

Comment: That was a typo on my part. I have done some work with structs, but a union? Or is that just another name?

Comment: Fix the question, it does not explain the problem properly.

Comment: For anyone that finds this question. I posted an edit to improve an old question.  Feel free to ignore this question.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do that. There is a way, but it is a bad practice, and you shouldn't use it. Here is a better option for that:

```
typedef union RAWINPUT_UNION
{
    char *string;
    int integer;
}RAWINPUT;

RAWINPUT rawinput(char *message, char *type)
{
    char *resultstring
    int resultinteger;
    RAWINPUT ri;

    // Blah blah blah some code here.

    if(type[0] == 's')
        ri.string = resultstring;
    else if(type[0] == 'i')
        ri.integer = resultinteger;

    return ri;
}
```

And the bad way is: You can perform integer arithmetic on a pointer, and store variables in it, because pointers are de facto integers, just with an addictional layer of abstraction in the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the return value needs to be a `char *` in one `printf("%s",...` and an `int` int `printf("%d", ...`, the **return type of the function should match the format specifier and be different between calls to avoid undefined behavior** (UB).  Let's use:

```
typedef struct {
  union {
    char *s;
    int i;
  } u;
  char type;
} raw_t;

raw_t rawinput(const char *message, char type) {
  raw_t r;
  printf("%s", message);
  r.type = type;
  switch (type) {
  case 'n':
    if (1 != scanf("%d", &r.u.i)) {
      ; // handle error;
    }
    break;
  case 's': {
    char tmp[1024];
    if (1 != scanf("%1023s", tmp)) {
      ; // handle error;
    }
    r.u.s = strdup(tmp);
    break;
    }
  default:
    ; // handle error;
  }
  return r;
}

int main() {
  printf("%s\n", rawinput("What is your name: ", 's').u.s); // Note .u.s
  printf("%d\n", rawinput("How old are you: "  , 'n').u.i); // Note .u.i
  return 0;
}
```

---

Take care of the memory leak in `printf("%s...`.